# What is considered ESD Sensitive and non-ESD Sensitive?

Tags: esd, electrostatic

For example, if an integrated circuit has an HBM rating of 8 kV but is now embedded in a circuit board, which is now installed inside an equipment assembly, I would think the ESD susceptibility of the part is greatly lowered at the equipment level.

Per MIL-STD-1686, at the component level an ESDS component > 16 kV HBM is "non-ESDS." What ESD susceptibility test would I use to determine if the completed equipment containing ESDS parts is ESD hardened to > 16 kV HBM such that it’s considered non-ESDS?

From my current understanding, equipment/system level (e.g., IEC) ESD tests are used to determine the robustness of external surfaces and ports of equipment containing ESDS parts. However, its known that HBM and IEC waveforms are different, with the latter being more severe.

If I have an external port (e.g., USB port) with an IEC 61000-4-2 8 kV rating, can I consider that non-ESDS and not invoke ESD precautions by not putting an ESD label on the port?  Or should I still put an ESD symbol next to the external port? I’m asking this question because our company is reviewing ESD protocols and I want to ensure were only invoking ESD protocols and labeling ESDS parts/equipment/external ports when necessary.

Based on my understanding of ESD testing/susceptibility, an IEC 61000-4-2 8 kV rated USB port provides enough robustness such that the internal ESDS component its connected to is ESD protected during equipment level handling/operation. Therefore, adding an ESD label to the USB port is unnecessary. From a consumer electronics interpretation, Apple, Google, HP etc., do not label their USB or Ethernet ports. I'm sure they've hardened their external ports, such that the consumer doesn't need to use ESD protocols when handling their equipment.

Comment: What relevant specifications do you claim for your products. Start there.

Comment: *I would think the ESD susceptibility of the part is greatly lowered at the equipment level.* Correct, in the equipment the sensitive parts are/can be protected from ESD by having no connections to the outside world (you cannot touch them) or they can be protected by ESD absorbing components.

Comment: I think @Bimpelrekkie comment qualifies as an answer to this question. So it is better to have it as an answer rather than a comment to this question.